# Writing Cleaner Python Code Through Seperate .py Files

Tags: python

I am a somewhat new to programming, and just started building my first real world project a couple of weeks ago.

I am working on a simple project that extracts my sales reps accounts receivables*(current, 30 days, 60 days, 90 days, over 90 days, and balance)*, saves data in individual excel files, and automatically emails it to each rep for their records (picture below is what I am extracting from):

[image: Table I am extracting from]

This is what the final excel product looks like:[image: excel final product]

**As of now, my code works perfect, BUT I have 8 separate .py files for each individual sales rep running the exact same code.**

This is what each .py file contains:

```
def run_sergio_script():
def customer_xpath():
    customer = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[2]").text
    return customer

def current_xpath():
    current = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[6]").text
    return current

def thirty_xpath():
    current = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[7]").text
    return current

def sixty_xpath():
    try:
        current = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[8]").text
        return current
    except:
        pass

def ninety_xpath():
    try:
        current = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[9]").text
        return current
    except:
        pass

def over_ninety_xpath():
    try:
        current = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[10]").text
        return current
    except:
        pass

def balance_xpath():
    try:
        current = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[11]").text
        return current
    except:
        pass

row_length = len(wb.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr"))
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("sergio Weekly AR Report.xlsx")
counter = 4

for row in range(1, row_length):
    sales_person = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[1]").text
    if (sales_person == "Sergio"):
        sheet = workbook["Sheet1"]
        sheet.cell(row= counter, column=1, value=customer_xpath())
        sheet.cell(row= counter, column=2, value=current_xpath())
        sheet.cell(row= counter, column=3, value=thirty_xpath())
        sheet.cell(row= counter, column=4, value=sixty_xpath())
        sheet.cell(row= counter, column=5, value=ninety_xpath())
        sheet.cell(row= counter, column=6, value=over_ninety_xpath())
        sheet.cell(row= counter, column=7, value=balance_xpath())
        print(sheet.max_row)
        counter += 1
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\test folder\\Accounts Receivable Weekly Reports\\Updated report")
    workbook.save("Sergio Weekly AR Report Updated.xlsx")
    workbook.close()
```

Again, my program works perfectly fine, but I am literally changing 3 lines of code for each `.py` file. It seems very repetitive, and I am sure there is a simpler way to do this. Before I go into bigger projects, I want to build a proper foundation. What would be the best practice to making my project more compact and readable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For reading settings in python, I suggest using YAML. The YAML files are human-readable and you can import them in 2 lines of python code.

Comment: This is opinion-based, so might be closed. I'd look into a library like configargparse, which will allow you to turn your 8 scripts into a single, parameterized program that can take args and/or a config file. Make those 3 lines you keep changing into _arguments_.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this tonight and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt do any of these if that was your requirement.. my solution would be far more simpler as below:

```
def parse_xpath(row, cell_location):
    try:
        current = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[{}]".format(cell_location).text
        return current
    except:
        pass

row_length = len(wb.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr"))
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("sergio Weekly AR Report.xlsx")
counter = 4
workbook_column_to_html_table_column_map = {
    1  2,
    2: 6,
    3: 7,
    4: 8,
    5: 9,
    6: 10,
    7: 11,
}

for row in range(1, row_length):
    sales_person = wb.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[1]").text
    if (sales_person == "Sergio"):
        sheet = workbook["Sheet1"]
        for key, value in workbook_column_to_html_table_column_map.items():
            sheet.cell(row= counter, column=key, value=parse_xpath(row, value))
        print(sheet.max_row)
        counter += 1
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\test folder\\Accounts Receivable Weekly Reports\\Updated report")
    workbook.save("Sergio Weekly AR Report Updated.xlsx")
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Arun. Although this is much cleaner code, is best practice to still have 8 different  .py sheets for each individual sales rep?  I also need to email each excel file to the specific sales rep, which will require me to create an additional 8 email files. Just seems very repetitive and not best practice

Comment: If all the sales rep names are available to you before hand, and the html table cell indexes are all static, you can always pass them as parameters to this python file.. But if you want to get the sales rep names from the html itself, then that is another bigger problem altogether.. what is your usecase here..